# Android 13 create a app specific folder in External Storage

Tags: java, android, android-studio, storage, android-external-storage

i need a app specific folder to store files (binary and text files) that my app is downloading from the internet and xml files that will be created by the app.
As it is neccessary to allow the user to copy files manually to this folder, i.e files that he recieves and exchanges via email or messenger, i cannot use the internal storage.
The app needs full access to the folder.
In the past i had a folder "MyApp" at the root path of the external storage.
I need a suggestion where and how to put the folder now, as it is not longer advisable to use the root path for a folder.

So what is the correct way to create a folder in the "Documents" folder of the device.
I don't need the full code for it but to mention special functions or methods that i schould use would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `SAF` to ask for the `Documents` folder read/write permissions & save/persist the returned `Uri` & use `DocumentFile` api to perform actions in that directory.

Comment: But isn't it mandatory to use a picker to access the files when i use the SAF?
My App doesn't use a picker to select the files.

Comment: You can use the system built-in picker provided via `SAF` & relevant `Intent` flags.

Comment: The App isn't using a picker, and should not use a picker, that is the problem.

Comment: Without using a picker to select a directory, it is not possible. However you can directly open the `Documents` directory for permission without having the user to 'navigate' to the directory to directory selection.

Comment: So, there is absolute no way to use the external storage without a picker?
When i use a browser or email and i download a file it is automatically stored in Downloads or documents folder without any anoying picker. How do this apps work?

Comment: You could use the barebones Downloads / Documents folder afaik to write files, but cannot create app specific folders in them or external storage.

Answer (score 0):

Every app can just create its own folder in the public Documents directory. And then create files in them. No saf needed.

The user can also with other means place files in your apps folder.

If your app wants to use those files you should use SAF OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user pick your folder. Upon which your app can list all the files in that folder.